# Is there an efficient way to count the occurrence of a huge number of strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, memory

I have to count the number of repeats for different strings in Java.  Those strings can be huge, come from several data sources, and a large number of the strings are repeated.

I need to get the only 20 from those strings with most frequency of every hour.

I considered counting the occurrence of each string, store them in a huge `HashMap`, with a `PriorityQueue` to keep the top string occurrence, but that will also consume a lot of memory.  At the start of every hour, the old hash map will be dropped, a new hash map would be created to count for the new hour's 20-top-frequent strings.  This could cause the JVM spend a long time to garbage collect that memory.

`String#intern` could help a little, but the `HashMap` is also a problem for the memory, and in the future I also want to store the aggregate data off-heap, but the uncertain distinct number of strings make it hard to estimate off-heap memory and the way to store those strings. Is there any advice to avoid map in off-heap?

I'm also interested in cardinality estimation，but seems hard to use it to count the number of replications of each string.

Comment: Have you looked into using `LinkedHashMap` ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hashmap, linkedhashmap can cause more memory fragments, and if I want to use the off-heap, arrays is prefer, like count is just a 4-bytes array, but how can I use estimatible memory to get top of count

Comment: It's not clear from your description why your hash map would take up a lot of memory. How many *different* strings would you be storing in it and what's the estimated total length of those unique strings?

Comment: OP, check out a SortedMultiset from Guava.  You can pass it a custom comparator so that you can easily find the top 20 most frequent strings.

Comment: In any case consider something like Redis or a disk-based equivalent. Then you will not be limited by VM heap size (and not limited by RAM/page file size if using a disk-based storage). But first actually test your algorithm to see how much memory it's really using, and increase heap size if needed.

Comment: As for a fast algorithm itself, consider a modified [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or generate a state machine from the search string(s). Both would be linear time wrt the sum of the length of the search string and string you're searching in.

Comment: for example, calculating a user's visit count, distinct ip and the top 20 of ip visit about a user, I want to use off-heap in the future, if a new ip comes, I can just allocate 4bytes to add the user's visit count,  and 4bytes to count the user's distinct count ip, using Cardinality Estimation, these can be pre-allocated, and memory usage is perfect, but when come to get top, pre-allocate memory can be difficult.

Comment: Your "for example" isn't relevant to the string counting problem you've posted. In any case have you *actually* run out of heap space with your string counting tests so far? The really has a slight scent of premature optimization to me.

Comment: I can't understand why you are suddenly talking about IP addresses? Can you add your estimated numbers and throughput into your actual question, along with the *real* description of your problem, since it directly affects the answers?

Comment: But why do you keep talking about IPs and users and traffic monitoring? Your question was about finding a string in another string, which has nothing to do with web site traffic monitoring. You need to clarify your question. Do you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure if my question involved finding a string in another string, I'm talking about how to count with less memory fragments, count the occurrence of a huge number of different strings in Java, not find in another string, ok...if my question is ambiguous, sorry for that, and I will correct it.

Answer (score 4):

A HashMap is the answer. It uses less memory than you think, because the map holds *references* to unique Strings, and uses O(1) space per entry. There's no getting around having to store one copy of each string, so a map won't cost much more memory than the (unique) strings themselves. Just accumulate the total occurrences of each string and use it to find the top 20.

If you run out of memory, you'll have to implement the map on disk, eg a relational database or NoSql, or something else. The principle of using a map (or map like structure) is the way to go.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I should continue using hashmap, but considered distribution, not off-heap

Answer (score 2):

I argue that a SortedMultiset from Guava would be easier to use in this case.  You can pass it a custom Comparator so that you can easily grab the first 20 entries (the most frequent strings).  It uses the same amount of memory as a Map implementation, and it automatically handles the accumulation for you.

Comment: in my previous implementation, I use hash map to aggregate all the ip's visit count of a user, sorted by a maxpriorityqueue, but that will consume a lot of memory and cause memory fragments, because in my case there can be so many users, so every hour will create so many sub-map to store the ip visit information

Comment: If you're looking for contiguous memory allocation, Java is not the language for you.

Comment: @daisydanngo You still haven't really told us how many search strings you're expecting. For example, 10,000 unique search strings, if you just use a plain `HashMap` or whatever, you grab the value set into an array and then sort, and it still won't put a dent in memory or take more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: we need to count a user's top ips, and the ip's top users too,  distributed to more node is a way, but low cache hit still